# Filtering an array with a "not something" condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models : User and Product. One product has only one User, as an owner. I want to collect all the products, except those the current_user already owns. So I did something like this in my **app/controllers/products_controller.rb** :

```rb
def index
  Product.all.each do |p|
    if p.owner != current_user
      @filtered_products = [ @filtered_products, p ]
    end
  end
  @products = @filtered_products.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

But I suppose it's not a good practice. Do you know something better ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a simple `where`?

```
def index
  @products = Product.not_owned_by(current_user).page(params[:page])
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def self.not_owned_by(u)
    where("owner_id <> ?", u.id)
  end
end
```

Also, when building arrays instantiate an empty array and then use `<<` instead of the reassignment thing that you're doing, it's about 4x faster and you also won't end up with a `nil` value at the first index.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all major databases support `<>` and `!=`. I'm not sure which is more widespread.